# Missing callable argument even if provided

Tags: python, class, instance

Given the following:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable

class Bar:
    def bar_meth():
        return [1, 2, 3]

class Foo(Bar):
    @staticmethod
    def foo_meth(a: int, b: int, base_func: Callable, *args):
        # sample code, it doesn't really matter as I'm sure this part works
        items = []
        for x in range(a, b):
            items.extend(base_func(args))

        return items

@dataclass
class Source:
    call: Callable = None
    args: tuple = None
    kwargs: dict = None

    def run(self):
        return self.call(self.args, self.kwargs)

class Binder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.source = Source()

    def bind(self, source: Callable, *args, **kwargs):
        self.source = Source(source, args, kwargs)

        return self.source

    def check(self):
        return self.source.run()
```

```py
# main.py
a = Foo()
b = Binder()

b.bind(a.foo_meth, 0, 50, a.bar_meth)
b.check()
```

All of this mess raises `TypeError: foo_meth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base_func'` at `return self._call(self._args, self._kwargs)`.
I checked with the debugger and `b.args = (arg1, arg2, <bound method Bar.bar_meth of <object and 0xAddress>>)`, so `bar_meth()` should be passed correctly.

I know this looks quite convoluted but I don't know how I could improve it, so if you don't have a solution perhaps you could offer some rework suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *unpack* `self.args` and `self.kwargs` when you do `self.call()` in `Source.run()`.

Change the function to:

```
def run(self):
    return self.call(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Looks like you also forgot to unpack the arguments to `base_func()` inside `Foo.foo_meth()`

```
def foo_meth(a: int, b: int, base_func: Callable, *args):
        # sample code, it doesn't really matter as I'm sure this part works
        items = []
        for x in range(a, b):
            items.extend(base_func(*args)) # <<------ Unpack here too

        return items
```

Now your MRE gives a different error --

```
TypeError: bar_meth() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is because you defined `Bar.bar_meth()` without any arguments, but you call it as `a.bar_meth(args)`. You will need to redefine it as

```
class Bar:
    def bar_meth(self):
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Indeed, I missed the unpacking. Regarding `Bar.bar_meth()` it was a mistake in the pseudo code. Thank you.